# Should multiple Spring controllers direct to same view file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Suppose in Controller A, I have

```
@GetMapping("/path/1")
public String getIndex() {
//it's own unique logic
...

return "path/to/file";
}
```

and in Controller B, I have

```
@GetMapping("/path/2")
public String getIndex() {
//It's own unique logic
...

return "path/to/file";
}
```

Is it a good practice to have two different mappings from different controllers direct to the same html (or any presentation) file? Should one mapping control all traffic to a particular view? Or should one of the controllers simply direct to the other controllers mapping?

Comment: I don't see any problem with having 2 controllers map to the same file.

Comment: I also don't see any problem it's totally up to your logic whether you want different view for two different controller mapping or else for any mapping you need only a single view.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, depending on your logic you could have Spring Controllers pointing to the same view file, it could reduce redundancy, I've seen many sites doing that, why add an extra file when things could work with one, it's not a bad practice, it's just what fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it isn’t a problem per se. But to offer a different view, you might wonder why do you need two different mappings to get to the same view. Could they be addressing the same domain problem?

You could probably have a single endpoint that takes arguments, and have the service layer do the very unique logics based on the arguments provided (it could even be the 1 and 2, passed as path params)

Controllers should not have too much logic anyway, it should only have the logic to populate the view with data received from the business / service layer, and probably both mappings will have to populate the same objects since it’s the same view. So that might be a better way of modeling it.

Hope it was constructive!